# What are the characters in this seal script inscription on an ancestral altar? (Characters identified: 孝思維則)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image: Seal script inscription on an ancestral shrine]

Hi, this four character inscription is on an ancestral altar which contains two spirit tablets. I am unsure of the more modern equivalents of these characters and would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

as @drooze revealed, it's "孝思維則"

reading from right to left:

孝: [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=孝](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%AD%9D)

思: [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=思](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%80%9D)

維: [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=維](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B6%AD)

則: [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=則](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%89%87)

the verse is original from 詩經　大雅　文王之什　下武:

> 成王之孚
>
> 下土之式
>
> 永言孝思
>
> 孝思維則

the ctext.org has a translation:

> He secured the confidence due to a king,
>
> And became a pattern of all below him.
>
> Ever thinking how to be filial,
>
> His filial mind was the model [which he supplied].

https://ctext.org/book-of-poetry/xia-wu

Answer (score 4):

The characters are **孝思維則**, which comes from a line in a poem called 《下武》 in the anthology [*Classic of Poetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_of_Poetry) - *Major Court Hymns*.

> 《詩經・大雅・下武》：「永言孝思，**孝思維則**」
>
> As an idiomatic expression removed from the context of the poem, this translates to:
>
> *[Man] must forever abide by [filial piety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filial_piety), for **filial piety is the moral code [of Man]***.

---

[image]

> 「孝」([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*qʰˤuʔ-s/** > [Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese): **/hˠau<sup>H</sup>/**, [*Fanqie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie): **呼敎切**, *filial piety*) is composed of
>
> - 「老」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*C.rˤuʔ/** > MC: **/lɑu<sup>X</sup>/**, *Fanqie*: **盧晧切**, *old*), both a semantic and a phonetic component;
> - 「子」(*child*), a semantic component.
>
> 「老」was later abbreviated to「耂」, as seen in the transition between forms A1 and A2.
>
> ## <kbd>A1
> [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 曶鼎
> [集成2838](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2838&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>A2
> [楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image]
> [郭・語3](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・61</kbd>
> 　<kbd>A3
>
> [篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>A4
> [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)102</kbd>
> 　<kbd>A5
> 現代
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 老
>
> 「老」was originally a depiction of an old, hunched person with unkempt hair grasping a walking cane. The cane later detached from the character (transitioning from B1-B2) and changed to the shape of「匕」(form B2 onwards).
>
> ## <kbd>B1
> [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8896
> [合集22246](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=22246&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>B2
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.2.6
> [合集36416](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=36416&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>B3
> 西周
> 金
> [image]
> 殳季良父壺
> [集成9713](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9713&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>B4
> 秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・雜](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)32</kbd>
> 　<kbd>B5
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 子
>
> 「子」depicts a young child.
>
> ## <kbd>C1
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2903
> [合集20576](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=20576&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>C2
> 楚
> 簡
> [image]
> [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・66</kbd>
> 　<kbd>C3
> 秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)62</kbd>
> 　<kbd>C4
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

[image]

> 「思」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*[s]ə/** > MC: **/sɨ/**, *Fanqie*: **息兹切**, *to think about / to miss*) is composed of
>
> - 「囟」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*[s]ə[r]-s/** > MC: **/siɪn<sup>H</sup>/**, *Fanqie*: **息晉切**), a phonetic component;
> - 「心」(*heart/mind*), a semantic component.
>
> The original form of the character is「恖」; in this character,「囟」was later merged into the shape of「田」, which is easily identifiable in the image.
>
> ## <kbd>D1
> [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 五年龏令思
> [集成11348](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=11348&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>D2
> 秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・為](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)49</kbd>
> 　<kbd>D3
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 心
>
> 「心」depicted a heart. The heart chambers later became exaggerated (E1-E2), then heavily abbreviated (E5 onwards).
>
> ## <kbd>E1
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3510
> [合集6](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>E2
> 西周
> 金
> [image]
> 史墻盤
> [集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>E3
> 楚
> 簡
> [image]
> [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・218</kbd>
> 　<kbd>E4
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>E5
> [魏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Wei)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image]
> 上尊號奏</kbd>
> 　<kbd>E6
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

[image]

> 「維」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*ɢʷij/** > MC: **/jiuɪ/**, *Fanqie*: **以追切**, *to bind/tie > to maintain/preserve*) is composed of
>
> - 「糸」(*fine silk*), a semantic component;
> - 「隹」(Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*ɢʷij/**), a phonetic component.
>
> **/*ɢʷij/** for「隹」is a lost phonetic line; the current pronunciation derives from **/*tur/** > **/t͡ɕiuɪ/**, **職追切**.
>
> ## <kbd>F1
> [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 蔡侯墓殘鐘
> [集成224](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=224&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>F2
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>F3
> 楚
> 簡
> [image]
> [曾](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)123</kbd>
> 　<kbd>F4
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 糸
>
> 「糸」depicts fine silk threads.
>
> ## <kbd>G1
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [京津](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)4487
> [合集28401](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28401&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>G2
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>G3
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 隹
>
> 「隹」depicts a bird.
>
> ## <kbd>H1
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)660
> [合集2317](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=2317&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>H2
> 戰國
> 金
> [image]
> 陳侯午敦
> [集成4647](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4647&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>G3
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>G4
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

[image]

> 「則」(*patterns* > *norms/rules*) is composed of
>
> - 「鼎」(*cauldron*), a semantic component;
> - 「刀・刂」(*knife*), a semantic component.
>
> The structure「則」originally described the carving of patterns onto bronzeware. Later on,「鼎」was abbreviated into「貝」, which is easily identifiable in the image.
>
> ## <kbd>J1
> 西周
> 金
> [image]
> 曶鼎
> [集成2838](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2838&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>J2
> 春秋
> 金
> [image]
> 曾子簠
> [集成4528](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4528&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>J3
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>J4
> 秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)39</kbd>
> 　<kbd>J5
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> ## 刀
>
> 「刀・刂」depicts a knife.
>
> ## <kbd>K1
> 商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3092
> [合集20349](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=20349&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>K2
>
> 篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>K3
> 秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡・日甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)26</kbd>
> 　<kbd>K4
> 現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 黃德寬《古文字譜系疏證》
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)